# Copy N random files from folder A to folder B in ruby

Tags: ruby, random

Suppose folder A contains 2000 files of same type. 
I would like to copy 1000 random files from folder A to folder B.
what is the easiest way to do that in Ruby!!

Thanks!
S

Comment: Where did this number *1000* come from?

Comment: 1000 could be any number less than 2000

Answer (score 3):

Hints :

- `Dir.entries(<dir>)` gives the list of filenames in the given directory as an array.
- `Array#sample(n)` gives you n random elements taken from the array.
- `FileUtils.cp(<src>, <dest>)` helps you copy a file from a dir to another (you need to require `fileutils` for this though.

Comment: "give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime". I removed my answer, yours is much better.

Comment: I disagree with the above comment. You really need a full answer. I had used this answer previously and I just ran into the bug of not filtering out ".." and "." in a directory. That's something a lot of developers may forget about and it needs to be stated explicitly